# drupal username hyperlink missing site url - ahref from user_load($node->uid)

Tags: php, drupal, hyperlink, drupal-7

I'm using the drupal FAQ module which sends an email to the admin [including the authors username as hyperlink](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/faq_ask/tree/faq_ask.module?id=9f4fbb7859c8fc24977f5d67cd589685236e442d#n1068), defined via:

```
'creator' => theme('username', array('account' => user_load($node->uid), 'plain' => TRUE)),
```

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/faq_ask/tree/faq_ask.module?id=9f4fbb7859c8fc24977f5d67cd589685236e442d#n480

unfortunately it only links to **/users/joeblock** and thus **missing the site url https://example.com** which means it won't work in emails.

```
<a href="/users/joeblock" title="View user profile." class="username">Joe Block</a>
```

I already tried the module **[pathologic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic)** hoping it adds the site url but didn't help ([perhaps because the rendered ahref includes a / infront of it](https://www.drupal.org/node/257026)).

Is it possible to modify the hyperlink just for this instance to insert the siteurl?

**Update:**
adding `$variables['link_options']['absolute'] = true;`into **includes/theme.inc** worked.

```
function theme_username($variables) {
      if (isset($variables['link_path'])) {
        // We have a link path, so we should generate a link using l().
        // Additional classes may be added as array elements like
        // $variables['link_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'myclass';
       $variables['link_options']['absolute'] = true;
$output = l($variables['name'] . $variables['extra'], $variables['link_path'], $variables['link_options']);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible! the faq module uses the theme username. This theme is defined in includes/theme.inc function theme_username

In your custom theme you can implement the template_process_username hook and alter the $variables array. 
The theme username uses the url function to create the url. This function accepts the absolute attribute to build an absolute url.

to create this function you can create a custom theme https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/howto/create-a-new-custom-theme-with-css-alone and put the yourthemename_process_username function inside the template.php file of your custom theme.
Otherwise you can add the function in a custom module.

Let's do an example with a custom module (with the markus name) because is much more common to create a custom module than a custom theme.
Create the site/all/modules/custom/markus directory.
Inside this directory create the markus.module file with this content:

```
<?php
function markus_node_presave($node){
    if( $node->type == 'faq' ){
        drupal_static('markus_faq_node_save', true);
    }
}

function markus_process_username( &$variables ){
    if( drupal_static('markus_faq_node_save', false) ){
        // alter the link_options only when you came from the ask module otherwise, without 
        // this if, all the username links in drupal will be absolute url.
        // Actually this is not a problem but it may be overkilling
        $variables['link_options']['absolute'] = true;
    }
}
```

create the markus.info file inside the markus directory with this content:

```
name = markus
description = "my custom module"
core = 7.x
package = "markus"
```

Now from the admin menu enable your theme.

It's better to implement the markus_process_username function in a custom module and not to edit the includes/theme.inc file because in this way you can update drupal much more easly. The drupal core should never be edited :)

Comment: Cool thanks @lastYorsh! Just not sure how to implement this into a custom theme. Do I need to create a module or put this code in a file within a custom theme? And what goes in the **if condition?** 
Currently, I'm using the main theme and tried it with adding `['absolute']= true` to the output within includes/theme.inc but didnt work "UNDEFINED VARIABLE in /MODULES/SYSTEM/MAINTENANCE-PAGE.TPL.PHP"  

`$output = l($variables['name'] . $variables['extra'], $variables['link_path'], $variables['link_options']['absolute']= true);`

Comment: My bad, it worked by just pasting `$variables['link_options']['absolute'] = true;` before the output :) Thanks again @lastYorsh you rock.

Would be great to know how I could implement this in a custom theme?
  Had a look at [creating Drupal 7 hooks](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/creating-drupal-7-hooks) but didn't fully understand.

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide some more informations :)

Comment: you rock! Thanks for taking the time, I'll try that out hopefully next week. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: I tried the module implementation, which I managed to make work without the if condition, thanks! How could I use the IF for limiting to ask module as per your comments in the code?

Also is there a way to load the hyperlink in a new tab for emails in a browser?

I tried adding  `$variables['link_options']['target']='_blank';` but it wasn't added.

Comment: I missed "[attributes]" , `$variables['link_options']['attributes']['target']='_blank';` worked :)

Comment: Hi, I've updated the answer to solve the if problem.
I needed to implement another hook, the hook_node_presave to setup a static variable (with drupal_static). This variable is true only when we are creating a new faq node.